# C++ Arrays: Stack vs Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory, stack-memory

In C++, how can you create a dynamic 2 dimensional array in the stack vs. in the heap? I am currently trying to complete and assignment that outlines the advantages and disadvantages of both. Any sources or links on the topic are welcome as well! thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any googling on this topic or looked for tutorials?

Comment: The main disadvantage of creating a dynamic array on the stack is that, in standard C++, you can't do that at all. Which makes the question rather moot.

Comment: Also why is this so heavily downvvoted?

Comment: @MikeSeymour you're right "dynamic on the stack" doesn't make much sense. You can have an object on the stack, like `std::vector` that holds an internal pointer to a heap block and that would be a dynamic array with a little part on the stack, lol. But what does dynamic mean anyway ? nothing is dynamic even on the heap. To resize you need to destroy entirely and reconstruct, so in both cases dynamic does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The most basic aggregate with 2 dimensions when declared and defined in the same place as automatic storage in a free function block will give you an array on the stack. However this is limited to the stack space, which usually is between 24kB and 1MB. So you cannot do big arrays. Also you can't move them or delete when you want since their life is tied to the program flow.

Heap is detached from program flow and it is up to the `malloc` function to decide where stuff goes. Usually it has a bunch of "bins" according to size request, and from a certain size (usually more than 256kB) it will ask the OS directly for a block using `VirtualAlloc` or `memmap`. In 32 bits you can allocate up to 2GiB and in 64 bits you can allocate up to when the swap space becomes full. At which points your process will be killed by the OOM or some other process.

I think those are the main differences